# Does Devise encrypt all user model attributes or only passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have some custom attributes associated with Devise users. Are these attributes encrypted by default? If not, how might one go about ensuring that all attributes of a user are encrypted?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just look at the data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Look at the data in the database. See that it's not encrypted. First part answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise will only encrypt the password. [attr-encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) looks like the most popular method of encrypting model attributes according to [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/encryption).